# How to use Material-UI Grid for SPA (negative margin problem)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use only `Grid` to create a SPA. I'm used to material-ui `Grid` and use it a lot, however in my new project I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Right now this is the problem:

[image: margin right]

There is a margin on the right side and a horizontal scrollbar.

I know about the negative margin limitation, but if I apply a padding to the parent element (as the documentation says), then my `Grid` element loses the full width functionality:

[image: using padding]

The horizontal scrollbar goes away, but then I have a padding on my elements, and if I set a `background color` in one of these elements, it doesn't apply to the full width, because there is a padding.

Using the `overflow-x: hidden` adds a second vertical scrollbar, and it seems I have to scroll two times vertically to scroll the page.

The only solution is using `Grid spacing={0}`, but then I don't get the spacing between sections and `Grid` containers inside sections also can't use `spacing`.

And example of what I'm implementing is in this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-volhard-e5yls?file=/src/App.js

My doubt is, what would be the best solution to have only a single page, and sections separating it. Ideally using one of the material-ui components.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<Grid> in material ui causes horizontal scroll- React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519275/grid-in-material-ui-causes-horizontal-scroll-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the root style to remove the horizontal scrollbar and margins. Material UI adds additional elements to achieve its styling so it might be a good idea to use the developer tools to find out what may be obscuring your css rules. As in this case, the div below the root one needed its margin removed and to be full width.

```
root: {
  display: "flex",
  flexGrow: 1,
  "& > div": {
    width: "100vw",
    margin: "0"
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-dew-gpxy2?file=/src/App.js:279-318

Maybe read more about the MUI styles API and how to use nested styles and rules.

Comment: The problem of this approach is that the Grid will have a padding, so it won't be full width. If I set the background color of one Grid item, it won't add the color to the whole row. Look at this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-mccarthy-f8jln?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It's the body, it has an 8px margin. Type `$0.style.margin = 0;` into the console and it'll remove it.

I imported a stylesheet for it: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-murdock-vzjxb?file=/src/index.js:61-82

Answer (score 1):

[MUI React Grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/) applies [negative margin](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#negative-margin) to the flex items if you use the ["spacing" prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#spacing). The goal is the total width of the items and the gaps to be less than the width of the flex container.

This leads to some additional side effects which bring complexity to the project, such as having a calculated CSS width more than 100%, for example `width: calc(100% + 24px)`.

I would, if possible, not use MUI React Grid at all. Try with CSS flexbox instead and do your own layout with the `Box` component. FYI MUI React Grid is implemented using flexbox under the hood. IMHO in 90% of the cases this will do the job, giving you more control and less of an unexpected behavior.

I created an example function that calculates the flex basis similar to the MUI React Grid split that uses the 12-column system. For example, grid item 4 is actually 4/12 = 1/3 ~ 33.33%. So you need a simple function to take into account the number of gaps and remove this extra space by reducing the width of the flex items (returns the `flex-basis` string value):

```js
export const calculateFlexBasisWithGap = (gapSizePx: number, totalItemsPerRow: number) => {
  const numberOfGaps = totalItemsPerRow - 1;
  const totalGapSpace = numberOfGaps * gapSizePx;
  const itemPercentage = 100 / totalItemsPerRow;
  const pxToReducePerItem = totalGapSpace / totalItemsPerRow;

  return `calc(${itemPercentage}% - ${pxToReducePerItem}px)`;
};
```

Hope this helps.

Best regards,
M.