# Why does my Gatsby/Material-UI site render slightly larger than the viewport?

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui, gatsby, static-site

I am using the [Gatsby/MUI starter](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/gatsby) as a boilerplate for my personal site. In my personal site, I am having the problem that all pages are rendering as slightly larger than the viewport size. This issue is consistent on mobile and laptop/desktop sized screens.

I am using MUI Grid. I have made sure that my meta viewport head element uses `width=device-width`. As far as I can tell this does not depend on fixed-size elements or grid spacing options, such as margin or padding.

Does anyone have any debug suggestions or would anyone like to see a particular piece of information that would aid in the debug process? Site is available at https://errcsool.com

[My code is available here](https://github.com/han-so1omon/errcsool.com)

Update: If I get rid of all pages except for index, this problem occurs as soon as I place something inside of an MUI with spacing options `<Grid container spacing={x}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Adding a root `div` element with `padding` at least half of spacing pixels, so for `spacing={8}`, the root div should have `padding={32}`.

[This is well-known functionality of Material-UI Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#negative-margin).

Related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942858/how-to-use-material-ui-grid-for-spa-negative-margin-problem).